# Prevent textbox from firing validators

Tags: asp.net, validation, textbox

So I have a textbox with 6 validators. 2 of each kind because I have two validation groups depending on what button the user clicks. My problem is everytime the textbox loses focus two error messages get displayed, and this looks wierd. I've tried setting the CausesValidation property of the textbox to "false" but it's not working.

Textbox & Validators -

```
<asp:TextBox ID="collectionDtl_Qty" runat="server" CssClass="formText" 
 AutoPostBack="false" CausesValidation="false" Text="0">
</asp:TextBox>
<asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="collectionDtl_Qty_Filtered" runat="server" 
 FilterMode="ValidChars" TargetControlID="collectionDtl_Qty" ValidChars="1234567890,">
</asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
<asp:CustomValidator ControlToValidate="collectionDtl_Qty" ID="collectionDtl_Qty_CValidator" 
 runat="server" ClientValidationFunction="coll_QtyValidator"
 Text="Quantity cannot be greater than requested quantity." ForeColor="Red" 
 ValidationGroup="formValidation" Display="Dynamic">
</asp:CustomValidator>
<asp:CustomValidator ControlToValidate="collectionDtl_Qty" ID="collectionDtl_Qty_CValidator2"
 runat="server" ClientValidationFunction="coll_QtyValidator"
 Text="Quantity cannot be greater than requested quantity." ForeColor="Red" 
 ValidationGroup="detailValidation" Display="Dynamic">
</asp:CustomValidator>
<asp:CompareValidator ControlToValidate="collectionDtl_Qty" ID="collectionDtl_Qty_Comparer" 
 runat="server" Text="Quantity must be greater than 0." ForeColor="Red" 
 ValidationGroup="formValidation" Display="Dynamic"
 ValueToCompare="0" Operator="GreaterThan" Type="Integer">
</asp:CompareValidator>
<asp:CompareValidator ControlToValidate="collectionDtl_Qty" ID="collectionDtl_Qty_Comparer2" 
 runat="server" Text="Quantity must be greater than 0." ForeColor="Red"
 ValidationGroup="detailValidation" Display="Dynamic"
 ValueToCompare="0" Operator="GreaterThan" Type="Integer">
</asp:CompareValidator>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hi according to your question.what i understand you have to disabled validator or use validation based on Button click.

1. For Button click use ValidationGroup

   ValidationGroup="save"
2. If you want to disabled validators on condition .Try this one

   ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('<%= rqrgvddlCategory.ClientID %>'), false);

   Hope it will helps you.